# Characterization for basis of generated topology

Tags: general-topology

> **Definition:** Given a set $X$ and $\mathcal{B}$ a collection of subsets of $X$, the topology generated by $\mathcal{B}$ is the set:
>
> $$[\mathcal{B}]=\bigcap_{\tau\in T}\tau$$
>
> where $T=\{\tau \in \mathscr{P}(X):\tau$ is a topology on $X$ and $\mathcal{B}\subset\tau\}$
>
> **Question:** Show that if $\mathcal{B}$ satifies:
>
> 1. $\mathcal{B}$ covers $X$, that is, $\forall x \in X$, there is a $B\in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x\in \mathcal{B}$.
> 2. $\forall B_1,B_2\in\mathcal{B}$ and $\forall x\in B_1\cap B_2$, there is a $C\in\mathcal{B}$ such that $x\in C\subset B_1\cap B_2$.
>
> then $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for the generated topology on $X$.

Almost everywhere I see the conditions in the question as the very definition of generated topology, and in the few places that said both definitions were equivalent, I didn't see a proof.

From 1, I got that (fairly obviously) that for every open set $A\in [\mathcal{B}$] we have:

$$A\subset\bigcup_{x\in A}B_x$$

where $x\in B_x\in\mathcal{B}$. But I got stuck when I tried to show the other inclusion for a subset $\mathcal{B}'\subset\mathcal{B}$.

I also tried by contradiction, only to- hit another wall.

Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: What is your definition of basis of a topology?

Comment: Hint: If you show $[\mathcal{B}]' := \{ \bigcup_{U \in S} U : S \subseteq \mathcal{B} \}$ is a topology under these conditions, (and easily it contains $\mathcal{B}$), then it's an element of the intersection forming $T$, so $[\mathcal{B}] \subseteq [\mathcal{B}]'$.  Then the other direction $[\mathcal{B}]' \subseteq [\mathcal{B}]$ should also be easy once you show $[\mathcal{B}]$ is actually a topology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set $\tau$ of arbitrary unions of elements of $\mathcal{B}$ is a topology.

It is clear that $X\in\tau$, because of property 1; also $\emptyset\in\tau$ (union of the empty family).

It is also clear that $\tau$ is closed under finite intersections. Indeed, suppose
$$
U=\bigcup_{i\in I}B_i,
\qquad
V=\bigcup_{j\in J}C_j,
\qquad
(B_i,C_j\in\mathcal{B})
$$
Then
$$
U\cap V=\bigcup_{i,j}(B_i\cap C_j)
$$
so it's enough to prove that if $B,C\in\mathcal{B}$, then $B\cap C\in\tau$. This is obtained applying property 2.

Since $\tau$ is a topology and clearly it is included in every topology that includes $\mathcal{B}$, we are done.

Comment: It isn't that clear that $\tau=[\mathcal{B}]$.Surely, both contain $\mathcal{B}$, but that doesn't prove the equality.

Comment: @AspiringMathematician Please, reread the last paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Take an open set $A \in [\mathcal{B}]$ and take $x \in A$. Then, as $[\mathcal{B}]$ is the smallest topology that contains $\mathcal{B}$, it follows that in particular $A \in \{\cap \delta \colon \delta \subset \mathcal{B} \text{ and } \delta \text{ is finite}  \}$, because $\{\cap \delta \colon \delta \subset \mathcal{B} \text{ and } \delta \text{ is finite} \}$ form a topology that contains $\mathcal{B}$.

By 2., it follows that for finite intersections, is still valid that there exists some $C \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in C \subset A$.

So $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for the topology $[\mathcal{B}]$